# Use two Wh-words in an interrogative sentence

Tags: grammar, british-english

Someone has written that - " Why is the promise of Ram Rajya not what I want as a woman?" Is it grammatically correct? Can I use in that way two WH words in a interrogative sentence?

https://feminisminindia-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/feminisminindia.com/2020/07/28/ram-rajya-modi-amit-shah-adityanath-bjp-safety-of-women-in-india/?amp_js_v=a3&amp_gsa=1&amp&usqp=mq331AQFKAGwASA%3D#aoh=15972548610653&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Ffeminisminindia.com%2F2020%2F07%2F28%2Fram-rajya-modi-amit-shah-adityanath-bjp-safety-of-women-in-india%2F

Comment: Of course you can. It's a bit stilted, though. Why is this what you want to ask?

Comment: I am bit confused with it. I think the sentence has an incomplete meaning and also it is grammatically wrong. But, if it's correct, tell me grammatical reason behind it for being correct answer.

Comment: Why is it grammatically wrong? It's the same structure as "Why don't you eat what I put on your plate?"

Comment: I want to ask merely if the sentence is correct, what is  grammatical reason behind it as per your answer? Dear 

Comment: Can anyone solve that confusion?

Comment: It's fine. The NP "what" is a prenuclear element in the NP "not what I want as a woman".

Comment: @tripleee Actually, I think it's the complement, not the object.

Comment: @tripleee "not what I want as a woman" is not a clause but an NP in a fused relative construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general structure of the sentence is

> Why is the promise of Ram Rajya not [complement]?

The complement can be a noun phrase, and "what I want as a woman" is a noun phrase describing a general class of concepts.

The fact that the complement begins with a "wh" word is not an impediment.